# How to customize a PlaceholderText in a Listbox to have a specific color in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am working on a `ListBox` where I have using `PlaceholderText` property of `TextBox`. Here is my code for the `ListBox`. I am using A `PopUp` to implement the content

```
<Popup x:Name="ReasonCodePopUp" x:FieldModifier="Public" IsOpen="{Binding ShowFuelChangeReasonPopUp, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                               Height="420" Width="1100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsLightDismissEnabled="True">
                            <Grid Height="397" Width="1100" >
                                <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" Name="txtFuelReason" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.FuelPlanInfo.ExtraFuelReason,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                <ListBox Margin="20" Name="lstFuelReason" SelectionChanged="lstFuelReason_SelectionChanged" 
                                     Background="#414042" Height="420" Width="1100" >
                                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>

                                        </Style>

                                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <ListBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Margin="43.5,30.5,748.5,0">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Reason Code"  FontSize="32"   FontFamily="Helvetica" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#ffffff"  IsHitTestVisible="False"  />
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                    <ListBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
                                        <Border Margin="43,0,57,0" BorderBrush="#979797" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Width="948"/>
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                    <ListBoxItem>
                                        <TextBlock Text="ATC"  Margin="43,0,57,0" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontSize="32" FontFamily="{ThemeResource Bold}" FontWeight="Normal" SelectionHighlightColor="Blue"></TextBlock>
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                    <ListBoxItem IsEnabled="False">
                                        <Border Margin="43,0,57,0" BorderBrush="#979797" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Width="948"/>
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                    <ListBoxItem>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Weather"  Margin="43,0,57,0" Foreground="#FFFFFF" FontSize="32" FontFamily="{ThemeResource Bold}" FontWeight="Normal"></TextBlock>
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                    <ListBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Margin="0">
                                        <Border Margin="43,0,57,0" BorderBrush="#979797" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Width="948"/>
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                    <ListBoxItem Height="50">
                                        <TextBox PlaceholderText="Other" Margin="43.5,0,0,0"  Tapped="FuelReasonOther_Tapped" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Foreground="#FF0078D7" FontSize="32" FontFamily="{ThemeResource Bold}" FontWeight="Normal" Style="{StaticResource TransparentTextBox}"/>

                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                </ListBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
```

I want to `<TextBox PlaceholderText="Other"/>`modify the foreground color of the "Other" as well as the text that is typed here to appear in `Blue`. 
I know I need to play with the `ContentTemplate` but not able to do so.

Comment: If the default template of [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx) is any indicator the Placeholder `ContentControl` in there is bound to `{ThemeResource SystemControlPageTextBaseMediumBrush}` so you could just override the `Brush` or go edit the template directly.

Comment: noob in editing that. Even my textbox is binded to a style, i cant overide that. Can you help me to modify my code?

Comment: You already have a custom style template for textbox? If so then sure just post the code. You should see a `x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"` on the one for Placeholder to change the `Foreground` of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override the TextControl defined brushes, you can change the colors to what you want without having to theme the whole TextBox control. I tested it with the following code, and it worked:

```
<TextBox PlaceholderText="Other" Margin="43.5,0,0,0" FontSize="32" FontWeight="Normal">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForeground" Color="LightBlue"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused" Color="LightBlue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver" Color="LightBlue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForeground" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundFocused" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundPointerOver" Color="Blue" />
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Note: I removed your bindings and event handlers to keep just the UI elements. But you should be able to add the TextBox.Resources to your TextBox and see it work.

The TextBox.Resources override the default brushes for TextControl (which is within the TextBox). These brush names are used by the control to draw in specific situations.

Let me know if this does the trick.